# How to adjust vertical position of axis.title.y once flipped?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I'm trying to ready a chart for a presentation. As a result I want to flip the y axis label horizontally which I have managed to do with the following:

```
iris %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))
```

However, at the same time for some unknown reason the title automatically justifies to the top of the y-axis. I can't seem to fix this.

I would like for the title to be centred along the axis once flipped.

I tried vjust but that doesn't do anything.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try and restart my session and see what happens.

Comment: Seems to be working after a restart. Thanks for letting me know it was supposed to work!